# jq + capture the tag value

Tags: json, jq

is it possible to capture the required tag value by *jq*

for example we want to capture the tag value - **version1531837630468**
while the input is **ams-env**

so jq will capture the tag value by ams-env

```
{
  "href" : "http://master:8080/api/v1/clusters/HDP?fields=Clusters/desired_configs",
  "Clusters" : {
    "cluster_name" : "HDP",
    "version" : "HDP-2.6",
    "desired_configs" : {
      "airflow" : {
        "tag" : "version1508837789535411",
        "version" : 2
      },
      "ams-env" : {
        "tag" : "version1531837630468",
        "version" : 7
      },
      "ams-grafana-env" : {
        "tag" : "version1531831836137",
        "version" : 5
      },
      .
      .
      .
      .
      .
      .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```bsh
$ jq -r '.Clusters.desired_configs."ams-env".tag' file.json
version1531837630468
```

The `ams-env` bit has to be quoted as it contains a minus sign.  Apart from that, it's straightforward.

If you want to pass `ams-env` as a variable on the command line:

```bsh
$ jq -r --arg var "ams-env" '.Clusters.desired_configs[$var].tag' file.json
version1531837630468
```

Comment: what in case we want to set the ams-env in variable for example - VAR=ams-env , then what should be the jq syntax ?

Comment: when I run it as ./jq -r '.Clusters.desired_configs."$VAR".tag' file.json , it not give any output

Comment: I try also this but without results - jq -r  --arg VAR "hive-log4j"  '.Clusters.desired_configs."$VAR".tag' file.json

Comment: @yael See updated answer.